# AngularJS access JSON array[n].property data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following response from a service in my AngularJS app:

```
{
  "people": [
    {"id": "b3b38689", "name": "Tom"},
    {"id": "a62e603f", "name": "Dick"},
    {"id": "da703c62", "name": "Harry"}
  ],
  "groups": [
    {"name": "group 1", participants: ["b3b38689", "a62e603f"]},
    {"name": "group 2", participants: ["a62e603f", "da703c62"]}
  ]
}
```

Ultimately this gets mapped to

```
$scope.data
```

Then, in my view I have:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="group in data.groups">
  <h1>{{group.name}}</h1>
  <p data-ng-repeat="participant in group.participants">...</p>
</div>
```

This is successfully outputting:

```
<div>
  <h1>group 1</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>group 2</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to put into the 'p' tags "people[n].name" of the entry that the id matches up.

Is anyone able to help me understand how I would accomplish this please?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Simplest would be if you could already include the user name in the group json object together with the id on server side.

Comment: on an angular solution, Im not sure whats the cleanest way.. maybe use a filter?

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to lookup someone based on their id. There are lots of ways to do this but one way would be to convert your people array into an object where the id field are keys. e.g.

```
$scope.people = {};
var peopleArray = $scope.data.people;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.people.length; i++) {
    $scope.people[peopleArray[i].key] = peopleArray[i].name;
}
```

Then in your html you can do

```
<p>{{people[participant]}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter `data.people` by the participant id:

```
<p data-ng-repeat="participant in group.participants">
  <span ng-bind="(data.people | filter:{id:participant})[0].name"></span>
</p>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wia1w1J495qoR9r9zUTf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter as below:

```
 <p data-ng-repeat="participant in group.participants">
      {{(data.people | filter:search(participant))[0].name}}
 </p>
```

javascript:

```
  $scope.search = function(name){
    return function(item)
    {
      return item.id == name;
    }
  };
```

Here is the plunker link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/oaHIw1c8U6l8YYIsaGfo?p=preview